# Right way to use lm in R

Tags: r, lm

I do not have very clear idea of how to use functions like lm() that ask for a formula and a data.frame.
On the web I red about different approach but sometimes R give us warnings and other stuff

Suppose for example a linear model where the output vector y is explained by the  matrix X.

I red that the best way is to use a data.frame (expecially if we are going to use the predict function later).

In situation where the X is a matrix is this the best way to use lm?

```
n=100
p=20
n_new=50

X=matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p)
Y=rnorm(n)
data=list("x"=X,"y"=Y)
l=lm(y~x,data)  

X_new=matrix(rnorm(n_new*p),n_new,p)
pred=predict(l,as.data.frame(X_new))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
l <- lm(y~.,data=data.frame(X,y=Y))
pred <- predict(l,data.frame(X_new))
```

In this case R constructs the column names (`X1` ... `X20`) automatically, but when you use the `y~.` syntax you don't need to know them.

Alternatively, if you are always going to fit linear regressions based on a matrix, you can use `lm.fit()` and compute the predictions yourself using matrix multiplication: you have to use `cbind(1,.)` to add an intercept column.

```
fit <- lm.fit(cbind(1,X),Y)
all(coef(l)==fit$coefficients)  ## TRUE
pred <- cbind(1,X_new) %*% fit$coefficients
```

(You could also use `cbind(1,X_new) %*% coef(l)`.) This is efficient, but it skips a lot of the error-checking steps, so use it with caution ...

Comment: ok thanks this works well. It seems strange but I did not find any quick explanation of how use ml and stuff like that.

Comment: Where did you look? Most people who use `lm` with a pre-existing matrix use `lm.fit`, but the convenience functions like `predict` expect a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like the one you describe, you have no reason not to turn your matrix into a data frame.  Try:

```
myData <- as.data.frame(cbind(Y, X))
l      <- lm(Y~., data=myData)
```