# When to use `y ~ .` with `lm()`

Tags: r, lm

I this link they show how to use `lm()` with a data frame

[Right way to use lm in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075822/right-way-to-use-lm-in-r/20076160#20076160)

However (being completely new to R) I'm still a little unclear on the systax?

Is there more that this addition of the `.` to `y ~`, or does it simply denote that you have moved from a vector input to a data frame input?

Comment: To what does the "T" in your question title refer?

Comment: The link explains that the `.` is shorthand for "all other columns" so `y ~ .` might be `column_y ~ column_a + column_b + column_c` if you had 4 such named columns. OK?

Comment: @GavinSimpson , maybe it's a typo (they meant "in R" rather than "in T")?

Comment: @BenBolker *slaps head* quite plausible. I should look down at me keyboard more. I'll edit the title...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.` notation in a formula is commonly taken to mean "*all other variables in `data` that do not already appear in the formula*". Consider the following:

```
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), A = runif(10), B = rnorm(10))
mod <- lm(y ~ ., data = df)
coef(mod)

R> coef(mod)
(Intercept)           A           B 
    -0.8389      0.5635     -0.2160
```

Ignore the values above; what is important is that there are two terms in the model (plus the intercept), taken from the set of `names(df)` that do not include `y`. This is exactly the same as writing out the full formula

```
mod <- lm(y ~ A + B, data = df)
```

but involves less typing. It is a convenient shortcut when the model formula might include many variables.

The other place this crops up is in `update()`, where the second argument is a formula and one uses `.` to indicate "*what was already there*". For example:

```
coef(update(mod, . ~ . - B))

R> coef(update(mod, . ~ . - B))
(Intercept)           A 
    -0.8156      0.5919
```

Hence the first `.`, to the left of `~` expands to "*keep the existing response variable `y`*", whilst the second `.`, to the right of `~` expands to `A + B` and hence we have `A + B - B` which cancels to `A`.